# Python - loop and iterable items

Tags: python

I have a quick question regarding loops and iterable items in python.
I have a data frame (DF) and the following loop:

```
for i, col in DF.iteritems():
print(i)
print(col)
```

I am not sure if I have understood correctly how iterable items work. How does python know that *i* are the variable names of the data frame DF and *col* corresponds to the rows?

I tried to look for some literature on this but couldn't find anything helpful. Can anyone explain this to me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`iteritems` gives an iterable of tuples.
Each iteration one tuple is fetched from the iterable.
The variable `i` will get the value of the first value in the iterable and `col` will get the second's.

Answer (score 0):

`DF.iteritems()` yields *two objects*, contained in a tuple, for each iteration. Python lets you unpack that into multiple variables.

In other words, what you posted works because the developer [read the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html) and knows that each `DF.iteritems()` element is an iterable with two objects inside.

You can also assign such an object to a *single* variable:

```
for name_and_col in DF.iteritems():
    print(name_and_col)
```

or unpack that tuple afterwards:

```
for name_and_col in DF.iteritems():
    i, col = name_and_col
```

because the target(s) in a `for` loop work just the same as in regular assignments.

Python itself doesn't have to know anything here. You as programmer just tell it to unpack each item in the iteration into two names. If there are more than 2 elements, or there is just one, or the item is not iterable, Python throws an exception.

Instead of a data frame, you could just build your own list to play with:

```
>>> demo = [
...     ('foo', 42),
...     ('bar', 'Eric Idle'),
...     ('spam', 3.145)
... ]
>>> for first, second in demo:
...     print(first)
...     print(second)
...     print()
...
foo
42

bar
Eric Idle

spam
3.145
```

This worked because each element in the `demo` list is itself a tuple with two values. We can elect not to unpack:

```
>>> for both in demo:
...     print(both)
...
('foo', 42)
('bar', 'Eric Idle')
('spam', 3.145)
```

but if we tried to unpack more we'd get an error:

```
>>> for first, second, third in demo:  # won't work, not enough elements
...     print(first, second, third)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

or if we tried to unpack something else, we'd also get an error:

```
>>> list_of_integers = [42, 81, 117]
>>> for first, second in list_of_integers:
...     print(first, second)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```